# Do we have a friendly English Primer for Programmers?

Tags: discussion

There are many questions about how to best handle English-as-second-language questions, answers, and comments, but I found none about *improving* the English of our English-as-second-or-third-language friends.

Consider: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/5672935/revisions

Editor Tarun attempted to improve the question by changing `I` to `i`, adding spaces before periods, and lowercasing the first word after periods. This might be idiomatic in his hometown, but it is not idiomatic English in the United States or any Commonwealth nation I've ever visited.

While I can (and did) point out the rules of English composition to him in a comment, my own comment is `Noise`, and probably misses a great deal many other small and large mistakes our English-as-foreign-language friends commonly make.

SO could benefit from a simple guide **English for Programmers**, and I'm curious if I overlooked an existing meta post with such a guide that I could use as a reference in future comments.

Comment: The poor soul must have been programming in C for too long, if he defaults to `i` rather than `I`.

Comment: No primer, but a full-fledged site. Off the top of my head, [Why should the first person pronoun 'I' always be capitalized?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/7986/why-should-the-first-person-pronoun-i-always-be-capitalized) [A space before a question or an exclamation mark. Can it be correct?](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/4645/a-space-before-a-question-or-an-exclamation-mark-can-it-be-correct/4646#4646)

Comment: @RegDwight, I've lost hours to English.SO myself :) but it feels completely out of scope for what's required: something that in ten or fifteen minutes specifies idiomatic English composition in a way that resonates with developers.

Comment: Hey, I'm just plugging our site. I know it doesn't fit your particular purpose. Never stopped me before. (^_^)